# alternatives to google maps for large-scale GIS viewers?

Tags: google-maps, gis

I would like to view a map of Indonesia / Australia / New Zealand like Google Maps, except that I'd like to customize the layers viewed: I'd like to use a topographic/bathymetric basemap, and show lat/long grid lines.

I just downloaded Google Earth and it's almost what I want except I don't want the spherical projection, I want a rectangular (Mercator?) projection.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Plenty of fish in the sea. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_geographic_information_systems_software

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a gratis program you can try [ArcGIS Explorer](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/explorer/index.html), which comes in desktop and browser versions. I quick search using the browser version didn't show any data sources for lat/long lines, but with the desktop AE you can [add a reference grid](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisexplorer/900/en/reference_grid.htm) (also called graticule).

Open source: For desktop use, using data from your own computer, have a gander at [Quantum GIS](http://www.qgis.org/). For using internet data and local data [UDig](http://udig.refractions.net/) is worth looking at. These are only two of a number of good programs, see [freegis.org](http://freegis.org/) for more.

If you have some money to spend [Global Mapper](http://www.globalmapper.com/) is very good at combining internet data sources and using different projections, and then of course there's the category defining (and expensive) [ArcGIS](http://www.esri.com/products/index.html). I've heard good things about [Manifold GIS](http://www.manifold.net/), but haven't done much more than look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Wikimapia](http://wikimapia.org) for it. It is also similar to Google maps.

Comment: interesting -- thanks! no lat/long grid or topo, though :-(

Comment: oh, never mind -- wikimapia classic has the topo/bathy.

Answer (score 1):

I'd second the idea for QGIS. The OpenLayers plugin will give you access to the regular base mapping: Yahoo, Google, Bing and Openstreetmap.

Comment: Which OS do you use QGIS on?  I can't get it working on Windows 7.  Seems to have some path errors or something.

Comment: Update: Workaround here:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30982/why-is-qgis-not-launching/31169#31169